# How to implement transaction in Redis when there're a lot of data to send?

Tags: python, redis

I'm using `pipelining` to make sure my two commands are executed in a transaction.

My code is:

```
with redis.pipeline() as p:
   p.delete(key)
   p.sadd(key, *many_ids)
   p.execute()
```

As you can see, I'm trying to replace a set with a new one atomically.
But this would result in `Error 32 while writing to socket. Broken pipe.` when `many_ids` becomes large (more than 1 million).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the trouble you have run into may be in expanding all your arguments. There is another way in which this transaction can be carried out; build your new set in batches. and then make use of the [RENAME](https://redis.io/commands/rename) operation

> Renames key to newkey. It returns an error when key does not exist. If
>   newkey already exists it is overwritten, when this happens RENAME
>   executes an implicit DEL operation, so if the deleted key contains a
>   very big value it may cause high latency even if RENAME itself is
>   usually a constant-time operation.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there's an atomic `rename` for `Reids` too.

Comment: From the question , i am not able to see as to how a rename solves the error specified by OP. A rename is great and works but how does it solve the Error 32 which seems more like a broken socket connection?

Comment: check this part of the answer `build your new set in batches` @Satyadev

Comment: Aah, i see , yes , the batching makes sense.

Comment: @Satyadev I can split my list into batches and create a new set, then use the atomic rename.